# CircleCI Android build failes with gradle 6.4

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, circleci

I'm trying to build my android project, but I'm facing an error I cannot really determine from where it comes:

> Task :data:generateReleaseRFile
>
> The message received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has
>   disappeared.
>
> Build request sent: Build{id=d4a47b41-7399-47f1-adbe-bc3bd46cb9ce,
>   currentDir=/home/circleci/project}
>
> Attempting to read last messages from the daemon log...
>
> Daemon pid: 133
>
> log file: /home/circleci/.gradle/daemon/6.4/daemon-133.out.log
>
> ----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-133.out.log -----
>
> Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$function$Predicate$-V-WRP` was not
>   found, it is required for default or static interface methods
>   desugaring of `boolean
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$CollectionView.removeIf($-vivified-$.java.util.function.Predicate)`
>
> Warning in
>   /home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.5/359e5e4f4784f23beb30ba454b41f6f992e58481/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.5.jar:java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.class:
>
> Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$IntStream$-WRP` was not found,
>   it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of
>   `$-vivified-$.java.util.stream.IntStream
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.ints()`
>
> Warning in
>   /home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.5/359e5e4f4784f23beb30ba454b41f6f992e58481/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.5.jar:java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.class:
>
> Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$LongStream$-WRP` was not
>   found, it is required for default or static interface methods
>   desugaring of `$-vivified-$.java.util.stream.LongStream
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.longs()`
>
> Warning in
>   /home/circleci/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools/desugar_jdk_libs/1.0.5/359e5e4f4784f23beb30ba454b41f6f992e58481/desugar_jdk_libs-1.0.5.jar:java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.class:
>
> Type `j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$DoubleStream$-WRP` was not
>   found, it is required for default or static interface methods
>   desugaring of `$-vivified-$.java.util.stream.DoubleStream
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.doubles(long)`
>
> Warning: Type `j$.util.OptionalConversions` was not found, it is
>   required for default or static interface methods desugaring of
>   `java.util.OptionalLong
>   j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$LongStream$-WRP.reduce(java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator)`
>
> Warning: Type `j$.util.LongSummaryStatisticsConversions` was not
>   found, it is required for default or static interface methods
>   desugaring of `java.util.LongSummaryStatistics
>   j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$LongStream$-WRP.summaryStatistics()`
>
> Warning: Type `j$.util.DoubleSummaryStatisticsConversions` was not
>   found, it is required for default or static interface methods
>   desugaring of `java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics
>   j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$DoubleStream$-WRP.summaryStatistics()`
>
> Warning: Type `j$.util.IntSummaryStatisticsConversions` was not found,
>   it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of
>   `java.util.IntSummaryStatistics
>   j$.$r8$wrapper$java$util$stream$IntStream$-WRP.summaryStatistics()`
>
> Parsing json file: /home/circleci/project/app/google-services.json
>
> warning: Current JDK version 1.8.0_252-b09 has a bug
>   (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720) that prevents Room
>   from being incremental. Consider using JDK 11+ or the embedded JDK
>   shipped with Android Studio 3.5+.[WARN] Incremental annotation
>   processing requested, but support is disabled because the following
>   processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
>
> /home/circleci/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1320:
>   warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did
>   you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.
>
> /home/circleci/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1322:
>   warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did
>   you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.
>
> /home/circleci/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1323:
>   warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did
>   you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.
>
> /home/circleci/project/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeReleaseResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:1325:
>   warn: multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did
>   you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?.
>
> w:
>   /home/circleci/project/data/src/main/java/at/guger/moneybook/data/migration/MigrationHelper.kt:
>   (26, 23): Parameter 'context' is never used
>
> w:
>   /home/circleci/project/data/src/main/java/at/guger/moneybook/data/migration/MigrationHelper.kt:
>   (30, 15): Parameter 'finished' is never used
>
> ----- End of the daemon log -----

You can find the full log on https://circleci.com/gh/guger/MoneyBook.

Comment: Is it a reproducible failure, or just a one-off? Try restarting the build? Also, you should probably disable the Gradle daemon on CI to make sure there's no shared state across multiple builds - you want your CI builds to be as hermetic as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately this happens all the time.

Comment: Gradle daemon should be disabled with `GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"` ?

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon

Comment: @Egor Well the build still fails though disabling the gradle daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with CircleCI's docker image, it's fixed now.